# Floating Point Texture Compatibility Mobile Three.js

Tags: mobile, three.js, webgl, gpgpu

I am trying to learn how to take advantage of the GPU for making more interesting applications. I am using THREE.js to make web applications that use the GPU and have been using floating point textures. I realized that none of these textures work on mobile (at least not on my phone), and tried looking up more about this problem. It looks like a lot of phones support floating point textures, but maybe WebGL doesn't interface with them properly? I use a galaxy s6. Is it just that my phone is out dated and newer phones can use them? After going online it looks like the newest iPhone doesn't support them, but I could also be wrong. Also I realize that the GPUS support floats, just not rendering to floating point textures. Any information on this would be greatly appreciated. After doing some research I feel more confused since a lot of it seems to contradict itself.

Comment: Seems like you answered your own question. [Many phones can read from floating point textures](http://webglstats.com/webgl/extension/OES_texture_float?platforms=0000007c0012800500) but can not render to them and often [can not filter them](http://webglstats.com/webgl/extension/OES_texture_float_linear?platforms=0000007c0012800500). Looking up [the GPU for the Galaxy S6 it doesn't appear to support rendering to floating point textures](http://opengles.gpuinfo.org/gles_generatereport.php?reportID=1663).

Comment: Wait, from the link you sed about the Galaxy s6, what about it says it cannot do floating point textures? Are there phones that even support this? I am having trouble understanding the first link as well. It looks like 68% of mobile devices support them? Thanks for the resources though.

Comment: After looking around, i figured out the first site. From the link about the galexy s6 specifically, I am unsure what says it cannot render floating point textures. is it the mali renderer?

Comment: Also just found out that half floats are supported on some devices for mobile which works well enough for what I am doing. Thanks for the help/resources

Comment: If you're looking at OpenGL ES info (not WebGL) then you'd see `EXT_color_buffer_float` listed as an extension if you can render to floating point textures. in WebGL2 the same is true. In WebGL1 you just have to enable floating point textures (ie. `OES_texture_float`) and if that succeeds then make a framebuffer with a floating point texture attached and call `gl.checkFramebufferStatus`. Seeing the S6 GPU doesn't have `EXT_color_buffer_float` means it can't render to floating point textures. It also appears it can't render to `half` either.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks a ton for the help. Yeah my phone doesn't work very well anymore so I am getting a new one and was testing an iPhone out and that could render to half floats. It looks like a lot of the newer phones can do half floats and even floats.